# can't run npm start after change the PC

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

## Edit

### I updated the Node version and it started working successfully

I changed my computer and moved all my React projects to the new computer but I can never run the npm start command, Note that the project was working properly before.
I followed all the instructions on the web and on the Stack Overflow website.

- Make sure that the npm version is above 6, the Node version is above 10, and that npx is present
- Make sure to add a script called start in the package.

**But this error appears to me**

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! small_buying_app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the small_buying_app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MASTER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-12-25T20_32_44_910Z-debug.log
```

**package file**

```
{
    "type": "module",
    "name": "online-library",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
        "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node index.js",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "sass": "^1.45.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: have you done `npm install` before?

Comment: yes i did and also used npm update

Comment: can you post your `pakage.json`?

Comment: try to go back and run `npm ci` instead of `npm install` and `npm update`. it can be a version compatibility problem between your dependencies.

Comment: I edited the question and added the content of the package at the end of it

Comment: Can you check and post the complete log from given directory?

Comment: @Abdulkerim Can you post your 2021-12-25T20_32_44_910Z-debug.log?

Comment: When i was try your package.json to install in my computer, it's completed on node js v14.17.2 version. Can you share your nodejs version or try it to upgrade v14.

Comment: I already updated the node version and it worked